# Eclipse C++: The word 'printf' is not correctly spelled

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to create my first C++ executable program with Eclipse in Windows 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
printf( "arg" );
}
```

I am getting error:

> " The word 'printf' is not correctly spelled".

Following are my configuration. How to overcome this error?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your file has extension .c or .cpp?

Comment: Funniest compiler error message I've ever seen :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you didn't give your C++ source a extension that is recognized as standard c++ file extension.

Could you rename your file as **main.cpp** so that eclipse treats it accordingly ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try changing the extension of the file with the program. As I see, it's currently just Main (without any extension) and eclipse is treating it as a simple text file, thus performing a spelling checking. If you change it to Main.c or Main.cpp, everything should be fine.